# SQL Python how to extend float array

Tags: python, sql

Hi i got a code which is looking for the id of my SQL output and trying to merge the results of the measures with the same id together like this

```
result = session.execute(stmt, stmt_args)
result2 = session.execute(stmt, stmt_args)
result3 = result2.fetchall()

for request_ts, identifier, ts, array_id, index, measures in result3:
        vals = vals_dict.get(array_id)
        if vals is None:
            # add record to index
            values = vals_dict[array_id] = {
                'id': array_id,
                'request_ts': request_ts,
                'identifier': identifier,
                'ts': ts,
                'value': measures,
                }
            # adds the same record to the relust list
            arrayvals.append(values)
        else:
            # # look up the record in the index
            vals['value'].extend(values)
```

so my Problem is that my measures are floats. So im getting the error msg
`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'extend'`
My Output without the else (extend) is:

```
{
    "result_array": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "identifier": "PortionMotor01",
            "request_ts": "Mon, 22 Feb 2021 12:12:27 GMT",
            "ts": "Wed, 17 Feb 2021 12:12:00 GMT",
            "value": 17.1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "identifier": "PortionMotor01",
            "request_ts": "Mon, 22 Feb 2021 12:12:27 GMT",
            "ts": "Wed, 17 Feb 2021 12:14:00 GMT",
            "value": 2005.0
        }
    ]
}
```

But there are only 1 measure per id in the result. I want this:

```
{
    "result_array": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "identifier": "PortionMotor01",
            "request_ts": "Mon, 22 Feb 2021 12:12:27 GMT",
            "ts": "Wed, 17 Feb 2021 12:12:00 GMT",
            "value": [17.1, 18.0, ...]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "identifier": "PortionMotor01",
            "request_ts": "Mon, 22 Feb 2021 12:12:27 GMT",
            "ts": "Wed, 17 Feb 2021 12:14:00 GMT",
            "value": [2005.0, 123.5, ...]
        }
    ]
}
```

my only problem is the extend... can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `vals` is `None` make the value for `'value'` a list containing the measure, change

```
'value': measures,
```

to

```
'value': [measures],
```

Now you will have a list containing one float value. Then in the `else` append the measure to the list (instead of extend), i.e. change:

```
        vals['value'].extend(values)
```

to

```
        vals['value'].append(measure)
```